# How to make a binary to string converter in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, binary, ascii

its a simple program:

A binary  to string converter

Im still sorta  new to programming i would really appreciate the help

i just need a small script that compiles and runs in Xcode

All the program  has to do is convert a a  binary string  and show  the hidden words/message.Thats all

like eg

0110001001110010011010010110000101101110001100010011001000110011 == "Brian123"

or like this website Binary to Ascii Text Converter

http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

***********************MY CODE SO FAR*****************************

```
- (IBAction)ConvertButton:(id)sender{



    NSString* makelink =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[_CharacterInput text]];




        NSDictionary *BinaryConverter=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                       ////number 0-9///////////////

                                       @"0011 0000 ",@"0",

                                       @"0011 0001 ",@"1",

                                       @"0011 0010 ",@"2",

                                       @"0011 0011 ",@"3",

                                       @"0011 0100 ",@"4",

                                       @"0011 0101 ",@"5",

                                       @"0011 0110 ",@"6",

                                       @"0011 0111 ",@"7",

                                       @"0011 1000 ",@"8",

                                       @"0011 1001 ",@"9",



                                       /////Small letters//////////////

                                       @"0110 0001 ",@"a",

                                       @"0110 0010 ",@"b",

                                       @"0110 0011 ",@"c",

                                       @"0110 0100 ",@"d",

                                       @"0110 0101 ",@"e",

                                       @"0110 0110 ",@"f",

                                       @"0110 0111 ",@"g",

                                       @"0110 1000 ",@"h",

                                       @"0110 1001 ",@"i",

                                       @"0110 1010 ",@"j",

                                       @"0110 1011 ",@"k",

                                       @"0110 1100 ",@"l",

                                       @"0110 1101 ",@"m",

                                       @"0110 1110 ",@"n",

                                       @"0110 1111 ",@"o",

                                       @"0111 0000 ",@"p",

                                       @"0111 0001 ",@"q",

                                       @"0111 0010 ",@"r",

                                       @"0111 0011 ",@"s",

                                       @"0111 0100 ",@"t",

                                       @"0111 0101 ",@"u",

                                       @"0111 0110 ",@"v",

                                       @"0111 0111 ",@"w",

                                       @"0111 1000 ",@"x",

                                       @"0111 1001 ",@"y",

                                       @"0111 1010 ",@"z",

                                       //CAPITAL LETTERS/////////////////////
                                   @"0100 0001 ",@"A",

                                   @"0100 0010 ",@"B",

                                   @"0100 0011 ",@"C",

                                   @"0100 0100 ",@"D",

                                   @"0100 0101 ",@"E",

                                   @"0100 0110 ",@"F",

                                   @"0100 0111 ",@"G",

                                   @"0100 1000 ",@"H",

                                   @"0100 1001 ",@"I",

                                   @"0100 1010 ",@"J",

                                   @"0100 1011 ",@"K",

                                   @"0100 1100 ",@"L",

                                   @"0100 1101 ",@"M",

                                   @"0100 1110 ",@"N",

                                   @"0100 1111 ",@"O",

                                   @"0101 0000 ",@"P",

                                   @"0101 0001 ",@"Q",

                                   @"0101 0010 ",@"R",

                                   @"0101 0011 ",@"S",

                                   @"0101 0100 ",@"T",

                                   @"0101 0101 ",@"U",

                                   @"0101 0110 ",@"V",

                                   @"0101 0111 ",@"W",

                                   @"0101 1000 ",@"X",

                                   @"0101 1001 ",@"Y",

                                   @"0101 1010 ",@"Z",

                                       nil];


    //////////// number 0-9///////////////


    NSString * Number0 = @"0";
    NSString * Number1 = @"1";
    NSString * Number2 = @"2";
    NSString * Number3 = @"3";
    NSString * Number4 = @"4";
    NSString * Number5 = @"5";
    NSString * Number6 = @"6";
    NSString * Number7 = @"7";
    NSString * Number8 = @"8";
    NSString * Number9 = @"9";





     ////////////Small Letterrs///////////////

    NSString * Lettera = @"a";
    NSString * Letterb = @"b";
    NSString * Letterc = @"c";
    NSString * Letterd = @"d";
    NSString * Lettere = @"e";
    NSString * Letterf = @"f";
    NSString * Letterg = @"g";
    NSString * Letterh = @"h";
    NSString * Letteri = @"i";
    NSString * Letterj = @"j";
    NSString * Letterk = @"k";
    NSString * Letterl = @"l";
    NSString * Letterm = @"m";
    NSString * Lettern = @"n";
    NSString * Lettero = @"o";
    NSString * Letterp = @"p";
    NSString * Letterq = @"q";
    NSString * Letterr = @"r";
    NSString * Letters = @"s";
    NSString * Lettert = @"t";
    NSString * Letteru = @"u";
    NSString * Letterv = @"v";
    NSString * Letterw = @"w";
    NSString * Letterx = @"x";
    NSString * Lettery = @"y";
    NSString * Letterz = @"z";

   ////////////Capital Letters///////////////
    NSString * LetterA = @"A";
    NSString * LetterB = @"B";
    NSString * LetterC = @"C";
    NSString * LetterD = @"D";
    NSString * LetterE = @"E";
    NSString * LetterF = @"F";
    NSString * LetterG = @"G";
    NSString * LetterH = @"H";
    NSString * LetterI = @"I";
    NSString * LetterJ = @"J";
    NSString * LetterK = @"K";
    NSString * LetterL = @"L";
    NSString * LetterM = @"M";
    NSString * LetterN = @"N";
    NSString * LetterO = @"O";
    NSString * LetterP = @"P";
    NSString * LetterQ = @"Q";
    NSString * LetterR = @"R";
    NSString * LetterS = @"S";
    NSString * LetterT = @"T";
    NSString * LetterU = @"U";
    NSString * LetterV = @"V";
    NSString * LetterW = @"W";
    NSString * LetterX = @"X";
    NSString * LetterY = @"Y";
    NSString * LetterZ = @"Z";

    /////////////Numbers 0-9///////////////////////


    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"0"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number0]];
    }

    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"1"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number1]];
    }


    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"2"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number2]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"3"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number3]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"4"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number4]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"5"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number5]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"6"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number6]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"7"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number7]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"8"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number8]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"9"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Number9]];
    }





    ///////////Small Letters////////////////////


    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"a"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettera]];
    }

    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"b"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterb]];
    }


    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"c"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterc]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"d"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterd]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"e"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettere]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"f"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterf]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"g"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterg]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"h"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterh]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"i"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letteri]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"j"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterj]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"k"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterk]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"l"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterl]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"m"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterm]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"n"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettern]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"o"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettero]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"p"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterp]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"q"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterq]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"r"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterr]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"s"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letters]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"t"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettert]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"u"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letteru]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"v"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterv]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"w"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterw]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"x"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterx]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"y"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Lettery]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"z"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:Letterz]];
    }




      ////////////  large Caps//////////////////////////////////////

    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"A"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterA]];
    }

    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"B"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterB]];
    }


    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"C"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterC]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"D"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterD]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"E"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterE]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"F"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterF]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"G"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterG]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"H"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterH]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"I"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterI]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"J"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterJ]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"K"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterK]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"L"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterL]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"M"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterM]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"N"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterN]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"O"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterO]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"P"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterP]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"Q"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterQ]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"R"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterR]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"S"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterS]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"T"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterT]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"U"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterU]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"V"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterV]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"W"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterW]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"X"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterX]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"Y"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterY]];
    }



    if ([_CharacterInput.text isEqual: @"Z"]) {
        [_BinaryDataTextField setText:[BinaryConverter objectForKey:LetterZ]];
    }




}



- (IBAction)RemoveKeyboard:(id)sender{

    [_CharacterInput resignFirstResponder];
    [_BinaryDataTextField resignFirstResponder];

}
@end
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? EDIT: It looks like you've been asking this since February so I'd have to assume you've tried something by now.

Comment: im still new to objective C.... i tried writting  the program but its super-long  and has soo many bugs and error i gave up like almost 600 lines of code  i can copy and paste it from my Xcode if you wanna c it

Comment: It may help to post the part where you're trying to convert the binary to ASCII

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go

```
NSString *str = @"01100010 01110010 01101001 01100001 01101110 00110001 00110010 00110011";
NSString *str2 = stringFromBinString(str);
NSLog(@"%@",str2); // brian123
```

This is the function that can convert

```
// Function that converts
NSString* stringFromBinString(NSString* binString) {
    NSArray *tokens = [binString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    char *chars = malloc(sizeof(char) * ([tokens count] + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < [tokens count]; i++) {
        const char *token_c = [[tokens objectAtIndex:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        char val = (char)strtol(token_c, NULL, 2);
        chars[i] = val;
    }
    chars[[tokens count]] = 0;
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:chars
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(chars);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the complete program since I'm in such a good mood today

```
//
//  main.m
//  HelpForBrianTheProgrammer
//
//  Created by Filip on 2013-06-25.

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
NSString* stringFromBinString(NSString* binString) {
    NSArray *tokens = [binString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    char *chars = malloc(sizeof(char) * ([tokens count] + 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < [tokens count]; i++) {
        const char *token_c = [[tokens objectAtIndex:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        char val = (char)strtol(token_c, NULL, 2);
        chars[i] = val;
    }
    chars[[tokens count]] = 0;
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithCString:chars
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(chars);
    return result;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSString *binString = @"0110001001110010011010010110000101101110001100010011001000110011";

        // Splitting the string into an array
        NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:binString.length];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < binString.length; i++) {
            NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [binString characterAtIndex:i]];
            [characters addObject:ichar];
        }

        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString new];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        NSInteger counter = 0;

        // Splitting the array into a string of blocks of 8 charachters with a space inbetween
        for (NSString *strPart in characters) {

            [str appendString:strPart];
            counter ++;

            if(counter > 0 && counter%8 == 0)
                [str appendString:@" "];
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",str);

        NSString *theString = stringFromBinString(str);
        NSLog(@"%@",theString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just to clarify; This code do work and get the following logs

> 2013-06-25 13:35:49.525 HelpForBrianTheProgrammer[16459:303] 01100010 01110010 01101001 01100001 01101110 00110001 00110010 00110011
>   2013-06-25 13:35:49.527 HelpForBrianTheProgrammer[16459:303] brian123

Comment: Seriously?! *(adding characters so that I can post comment)*

Comment: Xcode > File > New Project... > Command line tool.  Find main.  Insert code.

Comment: hey i just tried  copying and pasting the code it will not build it keeps comming up 19 errors. 19 Parse issues "Unknown type name 'NSString',"Unknown type name 'Protocol'...etc just copy and paste  and i hit build  ;(

Comment: Not to be mean - because we all start somewhere - but I'd recommend a more foundational understanding of the structure and function of C (and hence ObjC) programs so that you're better equipped to deal with the errors that arise when you are working to incorporate Filip's code into your own.  e.g. [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/)

Comment: maybe  im tired its 12midnight here in Auckland ..I hope one i'll be as good as you  thanks Filip

Comment: Worked like a Charm ;)!! i was using C template  instead of the foundations framework

Comment: @13rianC Great job! Don't forget to accept the answer. Happy programming! (btw go to sleep young man ^^)